# What does this error mean? "model.frame.default"

Tags: r

fit_logistic <- randomForest(y_train ~., data = x,family='binomial')

Error in model.frame.default(formula = y_train ~ ., data = x, na.action = function (object,  :    invalid type (list) for variable 'y_train'

Comment: It means that it think your `y_train` variable is a `list`. And `list` isn't a valid data type for that use. Can you post `str(x)` so we can see the structure of your data?

Comment: Couple other notes: you might want to look at the help page for `?randomForest` - it doesn't take a `family` argument. And I think your variable name `fit_logisitc` is bad - it implies a logistic regression, not a random forest.

Answer (score 0):

As suggest by Gregor maybe there's some confusion here, do you want to do logistic regression?
Then maybe you need to look into the `glm()` function:

```
fit_logistic <- glm(y_train ~., data = x,family='binomial')
```

`y_train` needs to be a column name of the dataframe called `x`.

Likewise, if you seek for a Random Forest model, `x` as to be a `data.frame()`, and `y_train` one of its columns.